# How to run Winrunner test scripts?

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

I am currently working with a legacy code and most of the unit test for this is written in Winrunner tool.
Unfortunately I am unable to find this tool to download, anyone has any idea where I can get this tool or is there any way to convert the already available scripts ?